# What can I use to manage the wires when replacing a looped ceiling rose light fixture with one that just has loose wires?

Tags: electrical, lighting

I'm changing a looped ceiling rose (LCR) light for a light that only has 3 connections, Live, Neutral and Earth.

The looped ceiling rose has 3 different metal parts that the wires go into, like this: [image: Looped Ceiling Rose]

(Image from http://www.flameport.com/electric/lighting_circuits/lighting_ceiling_rose_looped.cs4)

There's also an extractor fan wired into the LCR although if I can get the light wired in I should be ok with the extractor fan.

I guess I need the equivalent of the Loop, Neutral, and Line parts, but can't find anything that combines wires like this.

My plan was to recreate the neutral, loop and line 'combination' parts, with wires going from the line and neutral to the light.

My question is, in the UK, can I buy something to combine wires like this, similar to a Terminal Connector, but for multiple wires? Am I approaching this in the right way?

Comment: Don't you just need to marette the proper wires together?

Comment: I agree- just join the cables using a screw coupler or a block connector that is bridged. There is nothing special about that-e xcept that the junction box is difficult to buy.

Comment: @ppumkin, i've gone with your solution in the end (using a block connector), make that an answer and i'll accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a block connector (you can bridge it - on one side loop a a wire into each terminal to make it like one big connector)

[image]

or You can use a twist connector

[image]

I was searching for something like this. But an insulated version- i found something in china but the problem is it will never be approved to use that on internal circuits due to high risk of electrical shock. These are used inside distribution boards only - and can only be installed by qualified electricians.

[image]

Comment: +1, the wire nut is my choice.  Just get the right size so the connection is tight, and pre-twist the wires with a pair of pliers so they won't accidentally disconnect.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's possible to buy connector boxes that fit three or more wires. One vendor that makes them is WAGO, see [their products page](http://www.wago.us/products/terminal-blocks-and-connectors/installation-connectors/overview/)

[image]

I'm sure there are other brands, too, that was just one [recommended on a DIY forum.](http://www.ultimatehandyman.co.uk/forum1/one-or-two-choc-boxes-when-changing-a-ceiling-light-t67988.html)